# Use the ing form in past tense

Tags: past-tense

I found a phrase "I still remember playing while ...", it was a past tense I suppose but why is there not the "to be" for the -ing form? Why is *I still remember playing* correct without the "to be"?

Comment: There's also *I still remember [that] **I played** while …*, if you want to use the other verb form.

Answer (score 1):

"Playing" here is not a present participle, it is a **gerund**, i.e. a verb form that is used in place of a noun.

**Example**

The boy is playing. (present participle)

The boy enjoys playtime. ("playtime" is a noun and is the direct object)

The boy enjoys playing. ("playing" is a noun-equivalent and is the direct object of the verb "enjoy")